# Degree-constraints for the existence of vertex-disjoint directed cycle covers in digraphs

Tags: graph-theory, packing-and-covering, hamiltonian-graphs, traveling-salesman-problem, degree-sequence

Given a digraph $G(E,V): (u,v)\in E\implies(v,u)\notin E$, what is known about lower bounds on the indegree and outdegree of the vertices that guarantee the existence of a vertex-disjoint directed cycle cover?

There are [degree-constraints](https://arxiv.org/abs/1006.0590) for the existence of Hamilton cycles in digraphs and I would like to know what the "maximal possible relaxation" of those constraints is if a whole crew of salespersons were available for visiting the cities.

Comment: The existence of such cover is equivalent to the existence of a bijection $f$ from $V$ to $V$ such that $(x, f(x)) \in E$ for all $x\in V$. The criterion is given by Hall lemma, and the sufficient conditions in terms of degrees are provided by double counting of edges.

Comment: In Section 3.1 of the linked paper, an example is given which has no Hamiltonian cycle, but also cannot be covered with vertex-disjoint cycles.  So the semi-degree threshold for the existence of a Hamiltonian cycle in an oriented graph is the same as the existence of a vertex-disjoint directed cycle cover.

In the language of Fedor's comment above, note that the out-neighborhood of $A\cup D$ is $A\cup B$ and $|A\cup D|>|A\cup B|$.

Comment: Perhaps something interesting would happen if you drop the requirement that the cycles be vertex-disjoint?

Comment: @LouisD If the requirement of vertex-disjointness is dropped, the problem can be solved by bipartite matching by an almost trivial transformation that allows one to impose lower bounds on the indegree and outdegree of a vertex; requiring that they both should at least be 1 suffices. The transformation I refer to also rules out pairs of antiparallel arcs. So having tight degree constraints would yield alternative heuristics for the NP hard directed 3-Cycle cover.